# handle htmlinputbutton click on the server

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I have a simple htmlinputbutton of type "submit" in my aspx page.

```
<input id="Submit1" runat="server" type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

If I click it I want to handle this as an event on the server. Much like how a normal asp:Button would do.

EDIT: I've tried the onserverclick thingy...it didn't work. Used onserverclick="foo"

In my code behind did something like:

```
void foo(object s, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: So why not use a regular asp:Button?

Comment: just trying to see if I can capture the button which posted the form on the server...

Comment: Is your button inside a `form` that's `runat="server"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HtmlInputButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) provides a [ServerClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputbutton.serverclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="Submit1" runat="server" value="submit" onclick="" type="submit" />
```

In the onclick parameters you can put a custom event handler in java script.

If you want to use a code behind in the C# file I would recommend doing a post back and passing in the post back event arguments, and then have your page load catch those event arguments.  You can get event arguments using:

```
Request["__EVENTARGUEMNT"];
```